# Return array of objects with a jQuery plugin public method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm building a plugin, "selectList" that is built from a given array of objects with this structure:

```
var data = [
    {"value": 1, "name": "Item 1", "isSelected": true},
    {"value": 2, "name": "Item 2", "isSelected": false}
];
```

You can then click on the list's elements to select or unselect them (selected items add an "active" class). I want to invoke a public method when a "Save" button is clicked. This method will update the array received and update it with the selected items.

For this I have tried with this method:

```
$.fn.selectList.getData = function (elem, data) {
   var items = elem.children('ul').children('li').not('.sl-title');

   items.each(function (index) {
      if (this.hasClass('active')) {
        data[index].isSelected = true;
      } else {
        data[index].isSelected = false;
      }
    });

    return data;
}
```

This is how I've declared the variables inside my plugin:

```
;(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $.fn.selectList = function (settings) {

        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.selectList.defaults, settings);

        return this.each(function () {
            var _self = $(this),
                _data = opts.data;

            initList(_self);

            if (_data) {
                buildList(_self, _data);
            } else {
                noData(_self, opts.noDataMessage);
            }
        });
    };
...
```

I'm not sure where to pass `_self` and `_data` arguments to the public method, since the 'Save' button is not inside the plugin. Any help?